# How to train doc2vec with pre-built vocab in gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

I have 1000 documents.

For some purpose I need to keep specific words in the vocab. I tokenize the 1000 documents and I design a word_freq dict. e.g. {"word1":100, "word2": 2000, ...}

Now I want to build a doc2vec model using this word_freq.

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size= 300,
                window=300,
                min_count=0, 
                alpha=0.01, 
                min_alpha=0.0007,
                sample=1e-4,
                negative=5,
                dm=1,
                epochs=20,
                workers=16)

model.build_vocab_from_freq(word_freq=tf_idf_vocab, keep_raw_vocab=False, corpus_count=1000, update=False)

N = 942100020 # is the total number of words in the whole 1000 docs.
model.train(corpus_file=train_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                total_words=N,
                epochs=model.epochs)
```

To boost the training time, I used corpus file (SentenceLine) for training where each document is a line (document' words are separated by space).

Each document is expected to be tagged with its number in the corpus file (i.e. numeric tag.)

As a test, I trained the model for few epochs. To get the most similar word to a given document with e.g. tag=0, I use:

```
doc_vector = model_copy.dv[tag]

sims = model_copy.wv.most_similar([doc_vector], topn=20)
```

**I got an error in `doc_vector = model_copy.dv[tag]` said that tag=0 does not exist!**
I debug and it seems that model.dv is empty!

```
model.dv.expandos # {}
```

I checked the code of `build_vocab()`, at some point it call _scan_vocab() where it set the `model.dv` with tags.

However, in `build_vocab_from_freq()` it does not call _scan_vocab() and there is no tagging!?

```
def _scan_vocab(...):
    ....
    for t, dt in doctags_lookup.items():
            self.dv.key_to_index[t] = dt.index
            self.dv.set_vecattr(t, 'word_count', dt.word_count)
            self.dv.set_vecattr(t, 'doc_count', dt.doc_count)
```

Note that when I used `model.build_vocab(corpus_file=train_data, progress_per=1000)` to build the vocab internally, the documents are tagged with numeric numbers as I explained above!

Comment: What do you mean, "keep specific words in the vocab"? (If the words don't appear in the training texts, any vectors associated with thoe words will be worthless random noise – making this a nonsensical goal.) If you're getting a specific error, you should edit your question to include the full error/traceback you're receiving.

Comment: @gojomo instead of using trim_rule in build_vocab () where we can design a rule to, e.g., keep words that start with ABC (just to give an example) regardless their counts and apply RULE_DEFAULT for the rest, I process the docs offline to keep words that start with ABC and keep words that their counts > np.quantile(vocab.values(), 0.95). The error that I got is when I try to get the embedding of a doc using model.dv[tag], it throw an error because tag does not exist. As I explained, model.dv is empty dict!  looks  a bug as  build_vocab_from_freq looks useless unless I missed something

Comment: The `dv` object won't typically be a `dict` (though it will contain some `dict`s), and it'd be easier to understand the error you're getting if you could edit your question to include the full error/traceback you're receiving. (It's unclear why you're checking `model.dv.expandos`, and why you're working with a variable called `model_copy` when earlier code only shows creation of a `model`. Showing the exact code, & traceback, that triggered your error helps rule out lots of unshown errors.)

Comment: Separately, to better understand your setup, IIUC you have 1000 docs, with 942,100,010 total words across them (about 942K words per doc). That's quite different from typical `Doc2Vec` natural-language usages – even Tolstoy's famously-long 'War and Peace' was under 600K words! This suggests 2 other problems unrelated to your error: (1) mere 1000 contrasting docs unlikely enough to boostrap meaningful 300-dimensional vector-space; (2) an internal limit of Gensim *2Vec classes only considers the 1st 10k tokens of longer texts, so you're really just training on `1000*10k=` 1M words, not 942M.

Comment: You can work around that limit by splitting longer docs into 10k word chunks, then using the same `tag` for all chunks that "should be" treated as parts of one longer document – but you can't use that workaround with `corpus_file` mode, which forces tags to be the ordinal line-number of the related doc. (There are other sketchy choices in your parameters, likely against your intent, but let's solve the primary error you're asking about before going deeper into tangents.)

Comment: @gojomo thanks. I got where it mentions exactly the limit of 10K. gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx.
It is really weird cause the 942M is logged by gensim during build_vocab. Looks like they log before cutting the limit. So, it is quiet impossible to catch the problem!! Is there a way to display the real number used to train on ?

Comment: The 10k limit only applies in the Cython-optimized training loops during `train()` - not during pure-Python vocabulary-discovery. I don't know what you mean by "it is quiet impossible to catch the problem". There's a bunch of actual-training progress-reporting if you enable logging to the INFO level. However, given the depth of the 10k limit, much of the reporting will be tallying "words in examples trained-on" without regard to the implementation-limit trimming. The best practice is to ensure your training data has no texts with more tha 10k tokens.

Comment: I can log the effective words which is ~1M not 942M. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to just log the lower number of effective words, rather than fix the issue so that all words contribute.

Comment: @gojomo you are right. One last clarification. Because mathematically there is no limit on the sentence size, so, is it possible to create a local gensim copy and change that size from 10000 to e.g. 10M. Does it make sense ?

Comment: It's possible: all the source code of Gensim is available for you to customize however you'd like. But, once you start changing the Gensim code, installing the library becomes a bit trickier. And making a change like you propose – expanding a buffer in the optimized Cython code that's plenty for most users, at 10K tokens, to be instead 1000X larger might have significant memory-overhead & performance impacts. I recommend instead what I already suggested: splitting overlong docs into <10K token chunks.

Comment: I'd especially suggest against a sidequest of expanding that Gensim implementation limit while there remain other potential problems with your approach. Trying to make a 300-dimensional model from a mere 1000 docs of atypically-long size is suspect. Your custom vocab-limiting approach is suspect – you can probably achieve the same desired effect – unclear what it really is – with other more-typical options in a more robust way. It remains unclear if your original tag `does not exist` error has been fixed. And still, a bunch of your parameter choices are likely unwise for your aims.

Comment: @gojomo, this 300-d is just an example. I am using ray-tune to run different configurations. For example, for vector_size: I used [256, 512, 640]. What is a good value? I am not using anymore the build_vocab_from_freq() anymore as it does not provide tags. For the vocab, I implement trim_rule to reproduce what I explain in my question.

I agree, splitting docs to <10k is possible, however,  in my case, training will take forever as I am running many configuration with ray-tune, that is why i want to stick with corpus_file option to boost the performance by using multi-workers.

Comment: By all means if you have time/budget to grid-search many params vs some downstream eval, do it. But if your main interest is doc-vectors, 1000 contrasting docs doesn't seem rich enough, to me, for a 300d doc-model. That you're using PV-DM, and thus *also* training an (unstated) number of unique word-vectors against their local contexts, may help "fill out" the space - but note with a highly-atypical `window=300` word-to-word relations will have ~300x the influence on your final space as doc-to-word relations. So: you're mainly training word-vectors, throwing a few doc-vectors in on the side.

Comment: FWIW, my very rough/folk rule-of-thumb is for dense embeddings, your number of contrasting examples should be at least *squae* of your dimension count. EG: Want 100d word-vectors? Ensure you have at least (100^2=) 10,000 unique-word vocabulary. Bu size of your docs, odd `window`, & idiosyncratic vocab-processing makes me think you're not working on natural language. In which case: broader experimentation w/ params is more reasonable, but still be wary of anything that massively grows model state for less-varied training data, lest you trend toward severe overfitting/memorization.

Comment: I'm personally as wary of the clunky `trim_rule` as I am supplying one's own frequencies; if possible, I'd try to run a normal full vocab-survey via `build_vocab()`, then before `train()` delete unwanted words (by freq or pattenr) in one post-survey pass. If the motivation behind the giant `window` is that ordering/token-nearness not too important, you might want to go all the way to using a `window` larger than any document (every token is in every others' window), though unclear of perf impacts on such long docs.

Comment: Regarding your other parameters: those atypical `alpha`/`min_alpha` values are usually seen in poor-quality online tutorials by people who barely know what they're doing & just copy arbitrary weird choices from each other. (If you have a full evaluation to test different starting `alpha` values against each other, & you find larger better, more power to you – but it's rare for published work to start with `alpha>0.05`, & it's hard for me to imagine any advantage to a weird ending value like `0.0007` instead of default `0.0001`.

Comment: Also: in natural language, word-vecs & doc-vecs tend to *improve* for downstream tasks when you discard the large number of rare words, so a truly effective `min_count` that's tiny usually makes things worse. If you're trimming the 5% least-frequent words, that probably won't be a problem for you – as long as the rarest surviving words still have many varied contrasting examples. (If after your trim, you've still got surviving words with just 1 or a few occurrences, that might degard your other vectors for more-common words with the de facto noise of their unhelpfully-rare appearnces.)

Comment: `corpus_file` mode will achieve the highest core utilization/training rates, but if you've only got 16 cores, it's might not be wildly better than whatever ~8ish-12ish workers would achieve in classic iterable mode, even with its bottlenecks. Plus, that mode limits your tag-naming (to its int-per-line scheme) & thus your ability to work-around the 10k limit. And, still has some suspicious buggy behavior (https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/2757).

Comment: If you are in fact training many separate models for comparison, training, say, 4 models *in separate Python processes*, each with 4 workers in iterable mode, might achieve nearly-full core saturation, & same-ballpark overall-throughput, as if using `corpus_file` to fill all 16 cores in 4 sequential runs. (You'd still want your iterable as simple as possible – streaming raw already-tokenized text from disk – to minimize IO/in-process contention). To the extent runs only change post-vocab params, each can be started from a model that was `.save()`d after the `build_vocab()` step.

Comment: Ofc, every param change may affect overall runtime – so you wouldn't be assured of 4 models all wrapping training at the same time. And depending on vocab size maybe 4 models can't be trained in RAM at once. But if you're training, say, dozens of model variants, a process that's always keeping 4 in process could be pretty efficiently intense in terms of CPU/clocktime, only frustratingly suboptimal when the last 3/2/1 long-tail runs finish alone.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I'll will try the approach of splitting each doc into multiple sub-doc 10k having the same tag. Should I consider some overlapping ?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary; any overlap would oversample the tokens in that range. The artificial breaks do destroy some token-to-token context windows, but (again in usual natural-language, small-window situations) that seldom matters, because losing a handful of word-to-word contexts doesn't change much for word-to-word relationships appearing plentifully elsewhere.

Comment: (If your token freqs or overlong windows especially important to your data/goal, maybe that changes a little. If it was a big worry, you could test *large* overlaps – say half of each chunk - such that every range *except* the orphans at beginning and end appears twice. And such an artificial corpus-expansion would mean more training per epoch, so might need fewer epochs. But again, that's never a factor in usual natural-language applications, so I'd not worry about it.)

Comment: @gojomo I usually do this assessment (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html.) test to check that the model is well trained. I am wondering here `model.infer_vector(train_corpus[doc_id].words)`, should I use the whole document or I use up to 10K and then I take the average? Is there a limit of 10K even for `infer_vector` ?

Comment: That eval – checking that if you re-infer training docs, they get vectors "nearish" to same-doc vectors trained during bulk training – is a very crude 'sanity check' to be sure the model achieves something vaguely-self-consistent with regard the document-modeling intent. It's more a screen for whether a model has gone completely-off-the-rails than a reliable guide to which of multiple runs is best for *your* downstream purposes. So I'd recommend *against* using it to select the best model out of a large parameter search. Such decisions should be made on a project/goal-specific evaluation.

Comment: @gojomo I know. My model selection is based on a validation dataset which contains some words that supposed to represent the document.

Comment: `infer_vector()` uses the same optimized path, with the 10k limit, as training - given that inference is essentially training constrained to keep many values frozen.  So no matter what you pass it, it'll give you the inferred doc-vec for the 1st 10k tokens. That presents a problem for the above sanity check! If your docs are like, say, a real natural-language book – are they? – a 10k range in the middle might be very different (and thus get a very-different inferred doc-vector) than other regions.

Comment: The training workaround (repeating tags) effectively simulates making 1 doc-vec for any text length, but I can't think of how to achieve similar with `infer_vector()`. (It'd likely require new chunking-friendly functionality in that method – maybe not hard, but doesn't exist yet.) For model-eval purposes, this means that crude 're-infer self-similarity' screen may not work well. If you have some other project-specific way to tell a better set of doc- & word- vectors from a worse-set – as you should! – that may not much loss. (But of you needed later inference of >10k docs, that doesn't exist.)

Comment: I'll mention again: a bunch of aspects of your setup seem a bit far from usual uses of `Doc2Vec`. For example, most published work shows results on short texts of at least a few dozen words, but more often a few hundred or few thousand – like a comment or article. So using on a small number of multi-hundred-thousand-token texts is likely to still detect/model doc distinctions, but might not have same interprability & behavior as with smaller (focused-topic) texts. It may still work great for whatever your purpose is! But you're further from the 'centroid' of typical uses.